# Conditional probability intuition.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

[Kolmogorov definition - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#Kolmogorov_definition)
According to the Kolmogorov definition, given two events A and B, 
$P(A|B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$ .
But I dont really understand why this is true. Why isn't $ P(A|B) = P(A \cap B) $??

Somebody please help me get an intuition why the Kolmogorov definition is true??

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [blog post](http://oscarbonilla.com/2009/05/visualizing-bayes-theorem/). It's about a consequence of conditional probability, Bayes Theorem, but very helpful for visualizing how conditional probability works.

You can think about the $P(B)$ in the denominator as reminding you that you're in the $B$ universe; you want to know the probability of $A$ knowing that $B$ has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it has to be a probability, so certainty must correspond to probability $1$, not $P(B)$.

An example may be helpful.  Consider choosing (with equal probabilities) a number from $1$ to $10$.  Let $B$ be the event that the number chosen is odd, $A$ that the number $\le 3$.
If you know that the number is odd, that cuts down the possibilities to $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$,
still equally likely, of which $1$ and $3$ are still in $A$.  So $P(A|B) = 2/5 = P(A \cap B)/P(B)$.

Comment: Very good example, with this i can see how the sample space is transformed now to $\{1,3,5,7,9\}$

Answer (score 0):

$P(A|B)$ is the probability of $A$ happening, when you know that $B$ happened. This is not the same as $P(A\cap B)$, because then, you do not take into account that $B$ happened for sure. The probability of $B$ happening is $P(B)$, so you have to devide by that to obtain the probability of both of them happening assuming $B$ already happend, so $P(A|B)$.

**EDIT**
By definition, $P(A|B)$ is equal to
$$
P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}
$$
because usually, $P(B)\neq 1$, they are not equal.

Comment: I don't still understand why $P(A|B)$ is not the same as $P(A \cap B) $.